# PHP Get method not sending full input

Tags: php, get

I have a drop down list that is dynamically generated using a mySQL database using the following code:

```
$region = mysql_query("select region_name from region", $connection);

echo "<select name=region>Region</option>";

while ($row = $mysql_fetch_array($region))
{
  echo "<option value =$row[region_name]>$row[region_name]</option>";
}

echo "</select>"
```

This prints out the list perfectly fine however when I submit the form using the GET method any region name that has a space in it will not be passed through properly in the URL. Instead of "South Australia" it will only give me "South"

I know the URL should end up being:
http://foo.com/query.php?region=South+Australia

But instead the +Australia just doesn't appear.

Anybody know what stupid stuff I've done or what I'm missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use single quote for value in option tag:

**Try this in while loop:**

```
echo "<option value='$row[region_name]'>$row[region_name]</option>";
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your code.........

`echo "<select name=region>Region</option>";` should be

```
echo "<select name='region'><option>Region</option>";
```

and while giving value do this

```
echo "<option value='$row[region_name]'>$row[region_name]</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be because you're required to quote HTML attributes:

```
<option value="South Australia">...</option>
```

Otherwise, how is the browser supposed to distinguish between one attribute and the next?

```
<option value=South Australia>...</option>
```

The browser reads that as one attribute called 'value' with the value 'South' and another attribute called 'Australia'.

Try [validating your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/), it'll find other errors as well, as Starx points out..